# how to use a macro in excel

Tags: ms-office

The question is there are 'n' different ppts and I want to put all the ppts in one single ppt. Condition is I should not use copy paste rather I should write a function in excel using macros to get it done. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to automate PowerPoint from Excel. The [How to automate PowerPoint by using Visual Basic in Office 2003, in Office XP Developer, and in Office 2000 Developer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222929) article describes all the required steps for getting the job done. Be aware, the reference number corresponds to the Office installed on your machine. For example:

```
 Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library
```

Stands for PowerPoint 2013 and etc.